# Using divs to create table instead of table element

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a two dimension array and it can be iterated to create the table in angular. For unknown reason, the table is not showing. It means even when I put a simple table such as

```
<table style="width:100%">
 <tr>
   <th>Firstname</th>
   <th>Lastname</th>
   <th>Age</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
   <td>Eve</td>
   <td>Jackson</td>
   <td>94</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

It doesn't display. However if I put a simple `<p>test>/p>`. It shows up.

Actually ngOnInit was not called at all. But the constructor of the component was called.I don't know why. So I guess that maybe Angular 5 can't detect the table??

Thus I want to replace table with divs. Not sure how?

```
<p>Test</p>
<div class="uk-card">
   <table class="uk-table uk-table-divider">
     <tr *ngFor="let row of array">
       <td *ngFor="let field of row">
         <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="field.checked">{{field.text}}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/array-of-arrays-print-yjjgbm)

Answer (score -1):

Try to Implement the primeng component its having lot of option and features.

try this

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table